# Error - class does not extend System.Web.UI.Page

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have one error while compiling but it is strange because it did not move anywhere to happen.

The error is the following

'PaySimplex.FrontEnd.Pages.Operations.ParkingPayments.FinhishParking' is not allowed here because it does not extend class 'System.Web.UI.Page'.

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="FinhishParking.aspx.cs"           Inherits="PaySimplex.FrontEnd.Pages.Operations.ParkingPayments.FinhishParking" %>

<%@ Register TagPrefix="telerik" Namespace="Telerik.Web.UI" Assembly="Telerik.Web.UI" %>
<%@ Reference VirtualPath="~/Pages/Common/MovementsToolTip.ascx" %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head id="operationsParkingPaymentsHead" runat="server">
```

...

Comment: On the class of the page inherit from System.Web.UI.Page

Comment: Need to see the class definition for `PaySimplex.FrontEnd.Pages.Operations.ParkingPayments.FinhishParking` in `FinhishParking.aspx.cs`. I'm guessing it doesn't inherit from `System.Web.UI.Page`

Comment: Already solved my problem had the wrong namespace

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code-behind page should look like this:

```
namespace PaySimplex.FrontEnd.Pages.Operations.ParkingPayments
{
    public partial class FinhishParking : System.Web.UI.Page
    {   
        // removed
    }
}
```

The `FinhishParking` class could also inherit from another class or classes that eventually inherit from `System.Web.UI.Page`

Answer (score 0):

Make sure in your code-behind for `FinhishParking.aspx.cs` that the class you are inheriting from is `System.Web.UI.Page` or is a class that inherits from `System.Web.UI.Page` somewhere in its inheritance chain.