# " "is not allowed here because it does not extend class 'System.Web.UI.Page'

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

So I need to develop a web form to get data from the scanner. But I encounter a problem stating that " "is not allowed here because it does not extend class 'System.Web.UI.Page'.
As I'm aware that this topic is already been discussed, I still not able to solve it.

I have tried this steps but none of this working..

1. [Webform not allowed because it does not extend Class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43769508/webform-not-allowed-because-it-does-not-extend-class)
2. [Parser Error: '_Default' is not allowed here because it does not extend class 'System.Web.UI.Page' & MasterType declaration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2057817/parser-error-default-is-not-allowed-here-because-it-does-not-extend-class-s)
3. [Webform not allowed because it does not extend Class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43769508/webform-not-allowed-because-it-does-not-extend-class)

and already skim thorugh this https://weblog.west-wind.com/posts/2005/Sep/12/Understanding-Page-Inheritance-in-ASPNET-20 to understand more about the inheritance.

this is the lalala.aspx file

```
<%@ Page Language="C" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="lalala.aspx.cs" Inherits="TEST.lalala" %>
```

this is the lalala.aspx.cs file

```
namespace TEST
{
public partial class lalala : Form
{
// 
}
}
```

I really think that this error is cause by the page inheritance but I don't know how to fix it.. Please someone guide me

Comment: `public partial class lalala : Form` - What is the `Form` class? Does it inherit or extend `System.Web.UI.Page`? if not that is your problem.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Error - class does not extend System.Web.UI.Page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17552211/error-class-does-not-extend-system-web-ui-page)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this (presuming you are not using a master page):

```
namespace TEST
{
    public partial class lalala : System.Web.UI.Page
    {

    }
}
```

Comment: Yep-- even though it is called "Web Forms," the base class for all pages/forms is [`Page`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.ui.page?view=netframework-4.8).